# Largest sub-group in a list, but deterministic

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

In a list of e.g. 100 items with an integer value `IntValue`, I can easily group by these values.
`var groupby = list.GroupBy(i => i.IntValue);`

What is the best Linq-way to find the largest group in the `groupby` variable now?

It must be deterministic, so when there are two largest groups in the list with the same number of items, I would want to select te lowest value of `IntValue`.

Comment: [Actually](http://www.xkcd.com/1318/), what you want is an additional sort criteria, not "determinism".

Comment: Indeed. But in my case it serves the purpose to make the choice deterministic. Otherwise the additional criteria is not required or it doesn't make the choice better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do some ordering and take the first one:

```
var group = groupby.OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                   .ThenBy(g => g.Key)
                   .First();
```

You could achieve the same using syntax-based query:

```
var group = (from g in groupby
             order g by g.Count() descending, g.Key
             select g).First();
```

Comment: Didn't know of `ThenBy` clause.

Comment: You can get the same result with syntax-based query, compiler will figure out which method to call for you. I've updated my answer with that.